# What is the meaning of the category theoretic symbol $\nrightarrow$

Tags: category-theory, notation

I have read (I can't remember where) that, where $V$ is some set, the notation $\mathcal{P}(V) \nrightarrow \mathcal{P}(V)$ is used in category theory  to denote a binary relation $R \subseteq \mathcal{P}(U)\times \mathcal{P}(U)$.

Is this correct? If so, what is the definition of the symbol $\nrightarrow$ in category theory?

I have also seen as examples of such notation (in notes I took in some talk)

$$ A \stackrel{\text { some }}{\nrightarrow} X \Longleftrightarrow X \cap A \neq \emptyset
                $$

to symbolise the existential quantifier defined on some universe of discourse $X$, and where $A \subseteq X$. Is this abuse of the symbol ${\nrightarrow}$?

Comment: Never seen either of these before.

Comment: I suppose you mean an arrow with a small vertical (not slanted!) bar through the middle. This is indeed sometimes used to denote binary relations between sets, but more commonly profunctors between categories.

Comment: @Zhen Lin, ah ok, and why is this notation used for relations of this kind? Does it bear some particular significance in category-theoretic terms? If not, why not just use the familiar set-theoretic notation?